# Integrate Crystal Reports with Microsoft Visual Studio Lightswitch

Tags: crystal-reports, report, visual-studio-lightswitch, integrate

I've been browsing the web searching for an answer to this for a few weeks now, jumping back to other assignments at  work because I can't figure it out. I've searched google, youtube, stackoverflow, and several more websites. The typical solution I get is to right click on the project and add a new item; a crystal report. The problem is that crystal reports isn't included in lightswitch. So my question is, how would I go about working with crystal reports in Microsoft Visual Studio Lightswitch?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any information about anyone using Crystal Reports with LightSwitch. Is there some reason why you couldn't use SQL Server Reporting Services to create/display your reports? Maybe you didn't know about SSRS? It comes with SQL Server, so if you have a SQL Server license, you also have SSRS for free.

There's still no way for you to just right-click anything in a LightSwitch projectm in order to define a report, you'd still need to create your reports in SSRS , then display them (even passing parameters) with LS.

There's a little bit of a learning curve getting used to SSRS, but once you do, you'll find it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

i've been researching for three days and i've finally found a way around this: Open an aspx page from a lightswitch application that contains the crystal report viewer control and will therefore load your crystal report. Just follow these steps and let me know if you need further clarification;

1. Publish your lightswitch application (with a custom button control that will open the aspx page on execute). 
   I looked up the code for the _Execute() method here: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/11/Printing-Sql-Server-Reports-rdlc-With-LightSwitch.aspx
2. Open published lightswitch application as website in vs ultimate.
3. Create crystal report (add items, crystal reports).
4. Create aspx page to hold crystal report viewer control (that will load crystal report).

NB: Give read/write permissions to iis users on C:\Windows\Temp

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried consuming Crystal Reports in a LightSwitch application (yet), however I would suspect that you could leverage an existing Silverlight control that could take care of the work for you. It might take some tweaking to get the viewer to wire up in LightSwitch, but I am sure it can be done.

UPDATE... I stand correct; until someone else proves otherwise - I can't find anything that supports a Crystal Reports viewer in Silverlight.